# CustomCell in UITableView Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have created a UITableView and want to create cells on the fly to hold information such as a name, duration and price.

I have the following code:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data = [["name1","amount1","duration1"],["Name2","amount2","duration2"],["name3","amount3","duration3"]]


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][0])"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][1])"
    cell.price.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][2])"
    return cell
}

}
```

I get the following error on the storyboard :

The price outlet from the TableViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeated content.

I understand what the error means, however i thought that the MyCustomTableViewCell class meant that the price variable is dynamic and therefore not trying to repeat static content.

Any help would be appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Have you registered your Custom Cell XIB for reuse?

Comment: @DookieMan no i haven't, how do i go about doing that?

Comment: self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Askash however my code seemed to be a little confusing so I thought id post my answer incase anyone else has trouble with this.

**Step 1.** Ensure create a TableViewController with the following code and make sure its set on the storyboard:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var data = [["name1","amount1","duration1"],["Name2","amount2","duration2"],["name3","amount3","duration3"]]


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][0])"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][2])"
    cell.price.text = "£\(data[indexPath.row][2])"
    return cell
}
```

}

On the storyboard click on the TableViewController, click 'Show the identity inspector' and paste 'TableViewController' in the class section:
[image]

**Step 2** Create a new TableViewCell Class.
- Go File > new > File... > IOS Source > Cocoa Touch Class > Next
and create a TableViewCell class with a subclass of UITableViewCell:
[image]

**Step 3** Assign TableViewCell to prototype cell and set restoration ID.

click on the prototype cell within the storyboard, click Show the 'Attribute inspector' and paste 'TableViewCell' in the class section and within the identifier type 'cell':
[image]

**Step 4** create a outlet of the label 'Price' within the 'TableViewCell' class. (Using Ctrl + drag) and name it 'price'.

The code within the TableViewCell should look like the below:

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

}
```